# ctr pull: Always have to specify registry explicitly

Tags: containerd

I wanted to pull an image using `ctr image pull`.

However, it doesn't automatically use the main Docker hub when just using the image name:

```
ctr image pull e2eteam/busybox:1.29
```

Results in:

```
time="2023-09-07T07:08:18-07:00" level=info msg="trying next host" error="failed to do request: Head \"https://e2eteam/v2/busybox/manifests/1.29\": dial tcp: lookup e2eteam: no such host" host=e2eteam
ctr: failed to resolve reference "e2eteam/busybox:1.29": failed to do request: Head "https://e2eteam/v2/busybox/manifests/1.29": dial tcp: lookup e2eteam: no such host
```

However:

```
ctr image pull docker.io/e2eteam/busybox:1.29
```

works.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It should respect the file `/etc/containers/registries.conf`. There is some info on it on the web, for example:

- https://podman.io/docs/installation#registriesconf
- https://man.archlinux.org/man/containers-registries.conf.5.en

For example, writing this here to the file, should default to dockerhub as registry when not using a FQDN:

```ini
unqualified-search-registries=["docker.io"]
```

If this does not work, you can try to work with [containerd's host.toml](https://fossies.org/linux/containerd/docs/hosts.md)

```
$ tree /etc/containerd/certs.d
/etc/containerd/certs.d
└── docker.io
    └── hosts.toml

$ cat /etc/containerd/certs.d/docker.io/hosts.toml
server = "https://docker.io"

[host."https://registry-1.docker.io"]
  capabilities = ["pull", "resolve"]
```

Comment: Where should I put these files when using Windows? My `config.toml` is in `C:\Program Files\containerd`.

Comment: @rabejens, I dont know sorry. I was assuming your on linux or wls2. Maybe you can add that details to your question.